# C curl calls in system monitor

Tags: c, curl

I've written some C code that makes a call every minute to retreive crypto quotes using curl.  I get hundreds of lines in the System Monitor like:

Process Name sh, User Brian (Me), %CPU 0, ID 1868, Memory N/A, Disk Read Total N/A, Disk Write Total N/A, Priority Normal

I have 2 questions.  Will this hurt anything?  Below is a sample curl call, can I add anything to keep each call from showing up in the System Monitor?

```
cmd = popen("curl -s https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/MATIC-USD/spot", "r") ;
fgets(result, sizeof(result), cmd) ;
if (strstr(result, "}}") > 0)
    token = strtok(result, ":");
pclose(cmd) ;
```

Comment: You could, of course, just use libcurl from your application. I see nothing here that wouldn't be a trivial request for a curl_easy call set.

Comment: Just an OT question: is there a reason why you're not using a higher level language like Python for this?

Answer (score 0):

I did learn that the children staying in memory will cause the system to crash.  The work around I found was to remove the while loop from C, and write a shell script to call the executable every minute.  Because the children exit memory when the parent does, they don't build up in memory.  Thanks for the input